# A x10 oscilloscope probe means that the voltage is attenuated 10 times?

Tags: oscilloscope

I have a digital little oscilloscope that can handle up to 35 [V] in the input. 
As far as I know, we use x10 probes for high frequency circuits and that stuff but my doubt: if I have a x10 probe, does it mean that I can input to my oscilloscope up to 350 [V] p-p (because it would be attenuated to 35 [V] p-p)?

Comment: The *probe* might not be able to handle it.

Comment: Try it at a low voltage and make comparisons. The deal is that if your scope input is 1 Mohm then it's likely to be fine but test first.

Answer (score 3):

The 10x attenuation assumes that the oscilloscope has an input impedance of 1 MΩ. The probe itself has a 9 MΩ resistor in series (along with a capacitor for transient compensation). The actual voltage seen by the input of the oscilloscope is 1/10th of the voltage between ground and the probe tip.

While a 35V input is pretty low, I have seen the voltage rating of a (passive 10x) oscilloscope probe be lower than the attenuation factor times the voltage rating of the oscilloscope. I had a 10x probe rated for 400V, but the oscilloscope input was rated for 100V.